# Pros and cons of identifying relationship over non-identifying and vice versa

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys, relationship

Let's imagine simple real world `customer-loan` relationship scenario, where loan existence without customer is impossible, hence the relationship logically should be **many-to-one identifying relationship** with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` VARCHAR(50)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `loan` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `amount` FLOAT,
  `currency` VARCHAR(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `customer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `identifying_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

On the other hand, the same logic technically can be applied with **many-to-one non-identifying mandatory relationship** with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` VARCHAR(50)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `loan` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `customer_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `amount` FLOAT,
  `currency` VARCHAR(10),
  CONSTRAINT `non-identifying_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Question: What are the advantages and disadvantages of using identifying relationship over non-identifying relationship or vice versa? Are there any technical preferences choosing one over another?**

NB. One of the `disadvantage using identifying relationship` is `composite PRIMARY KEY`, which are generally difficult to maintain.

For example `PHP Doctrine ORM` does not support operating on such composite key, where one id is auto generated and the second key (foreign key) is the identifier of parent entity.

Comment: IMHO I think it is the schema that choose between an identifying-relationship and non-identifying relationship, it is not a mater of personal preferences. for example in your example there is no need for a composite primary key in the loans table since you have `id` *identifying* column.

Comment: Yep.  What @Accountantم just said.  I can see no point at all in PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `customer_id`) where id is already unique.

Comment: As the `id` is unique the composite `PK (id,customer_id)` has no meaning at all. It's like a `PK (id,currency)`. The mandatory part is the `NOT NULL` constraint on `customer_id`

Comment: @Accountantم Yup, I get your point, though asking not about personal preference, but also if there is any technical preference like in performance for example.

Comment: @dnoeth Yes, since there is `NOT NULL` constraint, that makes `non-identifying` relationship `mandatory`. So basically `identifying` and `non-identifying mandatory` relationships are somewhat the same on restrictions, but just the difference lays down on table structures.

Comment: It depends on logical data modelling, your 1st example is not properly modelled as `(id,customer_id)` is not a candidate key. Add another `payments` table, a `PK(auto_increment ID column)` (surrogate key) is non-identifying but `PK(loan_id, date)` (logical key) identifies. The 2nd is the correct implementation, because you still need another `unique` constraint on the combination when you only define the autoinc PK.

Comment: You are asking about identifying or non-identifying relationships, but your foreign keys are the same (but the name changes). Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer I am asking whether there is any performance preference in any way between aforementioned structures, since both of them are many-to-one relationships (but one is identifying and the second one non-identifying mandatory relationship)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an `auto_increment` column, then that should be the primary key.  In general, I avoid composite primary keys.  They just introduce scope for error in foreign key definitions and join conditions.  You also point out the limitation when using other tools.

I would expect this question for an n-m relationship.  That is one case where there is a good argument for a composite primary key.  However, in your case, loans have only one customer, so the second method seems more "correct".

Comment: I think the same that non-identifying approach technically is more preferable, though logically it should be identifying. For n-m relationship, in any case having mapping table with both primary keys of joining tables, thus the relationship will be identifying. Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I read about the difference between *identifying relationships* and *non-identifying relationships*.

In your example, you have a many to one relationship. As such, the loans do not qualify for an *identifying relationship*, because the customer id is not sufficient to identify a loan. Thus the relationship is *non-identifying*.

If each customer can have only one loan, there would be a one to one relationship between the loans and the customers. The customer id would be sufficient to identify a loan, thus we have an *identifying relationship*. In this case, it would be a good choice to set the customer_id column of the loans table as a primary key.

*Identifying relationships* are also used with the link table in a many to many relationship.